# Update rolling back without showing any error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app im trying to associate a Stripe plan to a user. I have implemented all the needed config and services for it.

But when I try to run a method, my transaction just rolled back, and nothing appears on my server console to give me a idea about what is happening.

Here is my classes:

```
private def create_client_subscription
  puts '****** CreateSubscriptionService:: START METHOD create_client_subscription'
  puts "****** CreateSubscriptionService:: #{token}"
    client.create_subscription!(
      customer: payment_gateway_customer,
      plan: payment_gateway_plan,
      token: 'test')
  puts '****** CreateSubscriptionService:: END METHOD create_client_subscription'
  end
```

And my client:

```
  def create_subscription!(customer: , plan: , source: )
    puts '****** STRIPE_CLIENT:: START CREATE SUBSCRIPTION'
    handle_client_error do
      customer.subscriptions.create(
        source: source,
        plan: plan.id
      )
    puts '****** STRIPE_CLIENT:: END CREATE SUBSCRIPTION'
    end
  end
```

The weirdest thing here its, that I can see on the server this puts line:

```
****** CreateSubscriptionService:: START RUN create_client_subscription
****** CreateSubscriptionService:: START METHOD create_client_subscription
****** CreateSubscriptionService:: 
  Talent Load (12.2ms)  SELECT  "talents".* FROM "talents" WHERE "talents"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Client Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Agency Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (26.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "payment_gateway_customer_identifier" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["payment_gateway_customer_identifier", "cus_DjNjsFkXZYKMz4"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-05 15:11:23.841589"], ["id", 1]]
   (9.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

So, my "create_subscriptions" method its never called. It doesnt even print this line on my console.

Any idea about what is happening, or how to see the errors on console?

Comment: What does `handle_client_error` look like?  I'd suspect that it surrounds the passed block in a `begin` `rescue` construct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, if you want to raise `RecordInvalid` error when creating objects, you should use `create!` instead of `create`.

> create!(attributes = nil, &block) public
>
> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. Raises a RecordInvalid error if validations fail, unlike Base#create.

Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create!